# Cannot able to get the data using rest api from TDengine cloud account

Tags: postman, tdengine

I got the 200 response succes but cannot able to get the response of my query. i want to show the data base available in the TDengine cloud account. And my query is SHOW DATABASES.
Anyone hlep me to get the data from the TDeninge cloud using the postman tool
[I am facing this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMl8U.png)

i am tried in postman and i want to get the data base list

Answer (score 0):

I don't know to convert to postman input but I use curl with proper parameters and seems it works good with TDengine cloud.

```
curl -i -N -d "show databases" https://gw.us-east.azure.cloud.tdengine.com/rest/sql?token=MYTOKEN
```